# How does $slot works in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to make a tab component using Vue.js. After going through documentation also, I am not able to understand how $slot works.

Tabs.Vue

```
<template>
    <div class="s12">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li v-for="tab in tabs"
                :class="[{ 'active': tab.isActive},  colspacing]"
                class="tab col"
            >

                <a :index="tab.index"
                   @click="selectTab(tab.index)"
                   href="#"
                ></a>
                <slot/> 
            </li>

        </ul>


    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['colspacing'],
        data() {
            return {
                tabs: [],
                activeTab: '',
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.tabs = this.$children;
        },
        methods: {
            selectTab(index) {
                this.tabs[index].isActive = true;
                this.tabs[index].addClass('active');
                this.activeTab = index;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Tab.Vue

```
<template>
    <section v-if="!isActive">
        <slot/>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {

            index: { required: true }
        },

        data: () => ({
            isActive: false,

        })
    };
</script>
```

And I am using it like this in my main app.vue

```
<tabs colspacing="s6">
      <tab index="attached">Attached</tab>
      <tab index="pending">Pending</tab>
</tabs>
```

As per my understanding, In Tabs.vue I have put slot inside li tag, so my tab component should render inside li component.Inside mounted method in Tabs.vue I am getting 0 children inside array.

While, If I pul slot outside  like this in Tabs.vue, it is working fine

Modified Tabs.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="s12">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li v-for="tab in tabs"
                :class="[{ 'active': tab.isActive},  colspacing]"
                class="tab col"
            >

                <a :index="tab.index"
                   @click="selectTab(tab.index)"
                   href="#"
                >{{tab.index}} ({{tab.size}})</a>

            </li>

        </ul>
        <slot/>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['colspacing'],
        data() {
            return {
                tabs: [],
                activeTab: '',
            }
        },
        computed: {

        },
        mounted() {
            this.tabs = this.$children;
        },
        methods: {
            selectTab(index) {
                this.tabs[index].isActive = true;
                this.tabs[index].addClass('active');
                this.activeTab = index;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone explain the reason why slot tag not working inside li but its working outside ul?

Comment: Whoever answers this, could you provide a general high-level overview of slot-scope in Vue components as well? I came across this when looking into Vuetify and although it's used in many places, I am mostly inferring what I think it means

Comment: Well, first, slot content is available in $slots, not $children. Specifically in this case, `this.$slots.default`. But that doesn't solve all your problems. You don't really want to include a slot in your template because you are wanting the parent to place the slot content.

Comment: @Bert I didnot understand what you mean.Because after changing position of <slot/> data inside $children is changing?

Comment: What I mean is you are not using slots as they are typically intended. In the code in the question, you are attempting to re-arrange the tabs passed in the slot and render them in individual `li` tags. A slot is not typically intended for that purpose, but rather as a placeholder for content that may or may not be provided. I'm not saying you *can't* do what you are thinking of, but you may need to resort to a render function.

Comment: I think you want something [closer to this](https://codesandbox.io/s/3x5rmnn2v5).